# How do I remove the "None" conversation driver seen in my input-view?

Tags: bixby

In my `input-view` for an optional concept, I see a `conversation-driver` name "None" which was not defined by me. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action input concept should be defined as `min(Required)` rather than `min(Optional)`. 
You can find more information on how to resolve this issue in our [help center](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021404353).